# Adding leading zeroes to a string date in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string "date" which can be DD.MM.YYYY or D.M.YYYY (with or without leading zeros), it depends what a user types.
Then I use it in a condition to send another email when the day is today.

```
if($_POST["date"]== date("d.m.Y")){ 
  $headers.="Bcc: another@mail.cz\r\n";
}
```

The problem is that the mail is send when the date format DD.MM.YYYY (with leading zeros) only.

**My proposed solution**

As I'm not very good in PHP, I only know the solution theoretically but not how to write the code - I would spend a week trying to figure it out on my own.

What's in my mind is dividing the date into three parts (day, month, year), then checking the first two parts if there's just one digit and adding leading zeros if it's the case. I don't know how to implement that to the condition above, though. I have read a few topics about how to do this, but they were a bit more different than my case is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should equalize to same format `d.m.Y` and you can do this with `strtotime` and `date` function:

```
$post_date = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($_POST["date"]));

if($post_date == date("d.m.Y")){ 
  $headers.="Bcc: another@mail.cz\r\n";
}
```

I changed `date` to `$post_date` for more clear. I'll try to explain difference with outputs

```
echo $_POST["date"]; // lets say: 8.7.2013

echo date("d.m.Y"); // 09.09.2013 > it's current day

strtotime($_POST["date"]); // 1373230800 > it's given date with unix time

$post_date = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($_POST["date"])); // 08.07.2013 > it's given date as right format
```

If you use `date` function without param, it returns as current date.

Otherwise if you use with param like `date('d.m.Y', strtotime('given_date'));`, it returns as `given date`.

```
$post_date = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($_POST["date"]));
```

At first, we converted your date string to unix with `strtotime` then equalized and converted format that you used in if clause.

Comment: check with strictly equal `===`

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. However I don't understand the first line much and I would really love to understand it. When I look at it I think that it rewrites the $date to the today's date but it doesn't, right? What is the difference between using date("format") only and date("format", function)?

Comment: You should definitely check `strtotime()` and `date()` in manual (php.net).

Comment: You're right Elon. Already did and now I understand, thanks for encouraging me - sometimes I just feel lost when reading the manual.

Comment: @TeeJay The answer updated. Check again. I hope help you with my great english ;)

Comment: Very nice explanation :) thank you for your kindness, I really appreciate it. I'm another little step forward in PHP now.

Answer (score 1):

first set date format with leading Zero

```
$postdate = strtotime('DD.MM.YY', $_POST['date']);
```

and also matching date will be in same format

```
$matching_date = date('DD.MM.YY', strtotime('whatever the date'));
```

then

```
if ( $postdate === $matching_date )
{
  // send mail
}
```

Comment: You seem to be also right. Just the "whatever the date" should be also date() function to make the date dynamic for every day without any code changes, right?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check the length of the _POST (it can be either 8 or 10)

```
if (strlen($_POST["date"]) == 10) {
   $headers.="Bcc: another@mail.cz\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Your solution will send the mail when it's 10th (or more) of October/November/December only. Furthermore, there are 3 options - 8, 9 or 10 characters (1.1.2013, 1.12.2013, 24.12.2013 - see?). Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, I had the impression that you are looking to send only when its 10 chars (eg 01.01.2012)

Comment: Never mind, that happens. Btw, the minus point you got isn't from me. +1 for trying.